# How to make an API only accessible through AWS API Gateway?

Tags: api, amazon-ec2, aws-api-gateway

I've built an API with Spring Boot and deployed it into an AWS EC2 instance. I want to make this Spring Boot API to be accessible only through AWS API Gateway. I mean no one could bypass AWS API Gateway and call the that API directly. I want to do this in order to  be able to apply some policies like throttling and others.
Is possible to make that API to receive calls through AWS API Gateway only?

Comment: Have you found a solution to this ? We are trying to anwser the same question.

Comment: Not yet. Unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

Your current best option to achieve this is to use the Client-Side SSL feature of API Gateway: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/getting-started-client-side-ssl-authentication.html

Note that if you front your EC2 instances with an ELB you will need to set them to TCP mode and terminate SSL on your EC2 instances.

Comment: What do you mean by terminate SSL on EC2 instances ?
Thanks